# How to check if a touch event is outside or inside of a region in android

Tags: android, android-touch-event

I have an image of a basketball pitch or any other pitch, and I want to check if the user checks outside or inside of 3 points area how can I achieve this? Shall I use predefined points of x,y?

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite clear what shape is the region? Triangle? Rectangle? There are algorithms online for a triangle, and for a rectangle it's just plain simple.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realize you meant the 3 point area in basketball. I meant 3 points, like A, B, C with their coordinates. Confused me a little :) anyway check out the answer

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if that area is a perfect half-circle, which I think it is, then the formula would be quite easy. You get X and Y coordinates of a touch event whichever way you prefer (that's not the issue here, use `GestureDetector` for example). I'll just give you an example of the `isIn3PointArea()` method:

```
private boolean isIn3PointArea(float touchX, float touchY, float centerX, float centerY, float r){
    float x = touchX - centerX;
    float y = touchY - centerY;
    return (touchX > centerX && Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y) < r);
}
```

Explanation:

> This is the method for the left 3 point area, for the right one you'd just need to swap out `>` operator with `<` in the `touchX > centerX` part. It's quite logical, your point needs to be less than **r** (which is the radius of your circle) from the center point (which has x coordinate of 0) and y, well whatever you give it, I'm not quite sure what you use to draw the court. Also it needs the `touchX` to be right of ( greater than **>** ) the `centerX` because if it's not, the touch is out of the field. The reverse logic applies to the right 3 point area.

The only thing that's up to you to deduce is what parameters to give to this method (you didn't share any code so I cannot know what your radius is or what are the coordinates of the court).

Comment: I dont have yet any code implemented your code I suppose is valid for any  screen size

Comment: Well this is just the basic idea, it needs some fine tuning and tweaking to make it actually work (depending on the way you draw the field). If you encounter any problems with it, write.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using x and y but believe me it will get very messy very soon. What I would suggest is use different image Views for different regions and add `onClickListeners` to the each of them . For this you will have to ask for different assets for each element in your court.